# javascript cloneNode with events

Tags: javascript, gmail, greasemonkey

I am working on a greasemonkey script for gmail where i need to make a copy of the "Inbox" link. Using cloneNode works ok, but i think there's an onclick event that gets attached to it at runtime. So, this is a two part question:
1. Is there a way to see what events are attached to a node? 
2. Is there a way to copy those events as well? 
The closest thing i found was jQuery, and i am not ready to go there yet. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Not unless it's set using the `onclick` attribute on the element.
2. Not reliably (you can copy the `onclick` attribute, but whether that will continue to work depends on if it was used and what it does).

You're better off adding your own `click` handler, and then triggering that event on the original... Or simulating the behavior in some other way.

Comment: I considered simulating the click event as well, but i can't find a reliable way of doing that either.

Comment: That's what i was looking for! I can just dispatch the click even on the original node. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think we can solve this stuff using this theory:

We have NodeList in JS, also called liveLists. We can check whenever their length changes, addEvent the desired common events to the new element in list at (length-1).

What say....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example using Nodelist for adding events.

```
<body>
        <div id="one" class="clones" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100px"></div>
    </body>

    <script>

        //Selecor based live list [Advantage]
        var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('clones')

        //Common Function for nodelist
        nodeList.addEvents = function(){
            nodeList.item(nodeList.length-1).addEventListener('click',function(){
                    console.log(this.id);
            });
        }
        nodeList.addEvents();

        //Making Clone
        var _clone  =  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].cloneNode(true);

        //Changing Id
        _clone.id="two"

        document.body.appendChild(_clone);
        nodeList.addEvents();
    </script>
```