# dojo clone event handlers

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I'm using `dojo.clone(obj)` for clone DOM node, but i don't know how clone event handlers. does anybody know how do this?

Answer (score 0):

If `obj` is a DOM node, it just does `obj.cloneNode(true)`.  It makes no specific attempts to clone events.  So, you are at the will of whatever events `obj.cloneNode(true)` clones, which has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815642/javascript-clonenode-with-events).